# How do i write an implicit Function conversion for a map call in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I write an implicit conversion for the code below (simplified)? I understand that you need to convert `(Int) => B` to `(String) => B`.

```
List(1, 2, 3).map { s: String => "_" + s }
// expected: List("_1", "_2", "_3")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Simon's answer works best. In case that you still want to do the implicit conversion the following should do the trick.

```scala
implicit def convertFun[B](fun: String => B): (Int => B) = {
  x: Int => fun(x.toString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Till. Yes that example was simplified, I was looking for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need, just do it like;

```
List(1, 2, 3) map { i: Int => "_" + i }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(s <- List(1, 2, 3)) yield "_" + s
```

Is this what you're looking for?